# Is it possible for a mobile webpage to capture a picture?

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications, mobile

Assuming you built a page for each specific mobile browser (Android/iOS/BB/etc.), is it possible to have a web application capture an image and send it to the server for processing?

I'd like there to be "Nothing to install" for my application, but if I need to reach out to the hardware at all, I fear it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Video Capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-capture-api/) but I have no idea how widely spread addoption is at present and it is very new.

IF this api isn't avalible there isn't really much you can do other then asking users to upload it using a standard file upload and them to take the picture before hand.

This is one area that a native application would be far far better as intergeneration would be easier and more seamless for the user.